# start haproxy without Sudo: Starting frontend http-in: cannot bind socket

Tags: centos7, haproxy

If I did execute haproxy from User with Sudoers right (Oracle Linux 7.5)

/data/haproxy/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

did start OK.

If I use User without Sudoers rights did return error: **Starting frontend http-in: cannot bind socket**

```
[WARNING] 197/182406 (115694) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for frontend 'https-in' as it requires HTTP mode.
[WARNING] 197/182406 (115694) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-basic' as it requires HTTP mode.
[WARNING] 197/182406 (115694) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-redirect' as it requires HTTP mode.
[WARNING] 197/182406 (115694) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'https-servers-service' as it requires HTTP mode.
[ALERT] 197/182406 (115694) : Starting frontend http-in: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]
[ALERT] 197/182406 (115694) : Starting frontend https-in: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:443]
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: It is impossible to bind to ports <= 1024 without root privileges, so this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, how would you solve this problem, if has to use user without sudo rights?

Comment: There is a difference between *starting* as root... and *running* as root.  Starting as root is standard practice as far as I know, and HAProxy -- like other software (e.g. postfix, nginx, apache) provides a way of dropping those privileges as soon as possible after startup, so that it can run unprivileged.  https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/management.html#13 Is this helpful?

Comment: I did try to use this way- Allow binding to ports below 1024. Did execute command: setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /data/haproxy/haproxy. This way did good result: haproxy did start.